# Import e-commerce transactions to google analytics

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to import my e-commerce transactions to GA. I decided to that with a [measurement collect api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide). Is there any other way to import transactions? In batches?

Probably, I'm just missing something but it doesn't work for me.

When I send `event` it works fine. I can see it on the real-time page.

```
import httplib, urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({
        'v': 1,
        'tid': 'UA-XXX-1',
        'cid': '36009a59-2a05-49e7-b826-2b884d0f935b',
        't': 'event',
        'ec': 'game',
        'ea': 'start',
        'ev': 0
        })

connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.google-analytics.com')
connection.request('POST', '/collect', params)
```

But when I send `transaction` and `item`. I can't see any activity on the real-time GA page.

```
import httplib, urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({
        'v': 1,
        'tid': 'UA-XXX-1',
        'cid': '36009a59-2a05-49e7-b826-2b884d0f935b',
        't': 'transaction',
        'ti': '1234X',
        'ta': 'tesco',
        'tr': 100,
        'cu': 'EUR'
})

connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.google-analytics.com')
result = connection.request('POST', '/collect', params)
```

,

```
import httplib, urllib


params = urllib.urlencode({
        'v': 1,
        'tid': 'UA-XXX-1',
        'cid': '36009a59-2a05-49e7-b826-2b884d0f935b',
        't': 'item',
        'ti': '1234X',
        'in': 'sofa',
        'ip': 100,
        'iq': 1,
        'ic': 'u3eqds43',
        'iv': 'furniture',
        'cu': 'EUR'
})

connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.google-analytics.com')
result = connection.request('POST', '/collect', params)
```

Also, I enabled e-commerce in GA -> Admin -> Ecommerce set-up

So, what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found the error?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp it doesn't seem to be possible in GA as I remember

Comment: So your question is how to be able to see ecommerce activities in real time? By the way, what's the "key" for "item_id"? There's transaction_id (ti), item_name (in) but there's no "item id", whereas it does exist in javascript version of google analytics.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp sorry, I do not remember now.